# InDesign CS6 - Update multiple displayed artboard/pages of linked files without relinking

Tags: adobe-indesign, artboard, optimization

InDesign CS6.

I'd like to know if there is a way of updating a linked file's displayed artboard (.ai) or page (.pdf) without having to go through the process of relinking the file.

Currently upon adding a new artboard to a linked .AI I need to go through every instance of that link and:

1. Browse for the file
2. Select the import options
3. Confirm Relink

This gets tiresome when for example I have a file that is linked in several objects and for which different artboards are used at the same time inside the IND document.

Just to clarify: I keep different versions of an icon inside one .AI so that modifying colors and symbols can be done in a single operation (as opposed to a workflow where you have one .AI for every icon version)

The links panel seems to show the currently selected artboard in this format

```
filename.extension:artboardnumber
```

[image: links panel]

**Is there a way to quickly change that artboard number?**

Thanks

Comment: At the moment the most efficient way of updating a displayed artboard across multiple instances seems to use the Content Conveyor or the Paste and Link function to create linked objects, update the original object once and then Update All Links. This however requires some advance planning :-)

Comment: If I remember correctly, all you have to do is close the indesign file, replace/update the AI file and reopen the indesign file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that could help me with switching displayed artboards in objects containing linked files.

Comment: I don't think you can to be honest. Primarily since the file is linked correctly and you merely want to change the import options. There's no feature I'm aware of to alter import options on more than one image at a time. Using separate files rather than artboards would be easier, but I have no idea if that's feasible in your situation.

Comment: That's not what you asked, really. I design updates the files when it starts up. So that should update your views of the file.

Comment: I thought all you had to do was click the `update` button next to relink?

Answer (score 1):

As Scott points out in his comment, what you are doing is updating the import options, not really changing the link, and the functionality isn't exposed in the UI. It could be scripted.

Here is a workaround: When you create your new artboard, swap its content with the artboard that is currently linked, then save the file. All of your existing links can then be refreshed, rather than relinked.

Another possibility that I haven't tested would be to rename the out-of-date artboard, then name the new one with the original's name. I don't know that Id is smart enough to recognize that, rather than simply going by the sequence in which they were created. Might be worth a test, though.

Comment: Exactly, what seems to be missing in InDesign is a way to update the import options without reimporting files from scratch. The workaround you provide is not ideal for my case as I don't have an "out of date" artboard, rather I have different versions of the same artwork in different artboards and I need to be able to quickly switch from one to another. For an "out of date artboard" you can simply change the artboards order in the artboard panel without replacing anything and that does the trick, no renaming is needed.

Comment: (InDesign doesn't care about naming, it considers only artboards/pages numbering)

Comment: I can think of one possibility: keep your master AI file separate, save out the current artboard as its own file and link that (overwrite with a new artboard when it changes). The application isn't built for the workflow you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the layer visibility is editable via the "objects" menu: `objects > object layer options`. I do not think you can do this on a mass basis however, so it is once per object link.

AI artboards appear as "pages" in the initial import options dialog. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way inside the user interface to change the page number for PDF and AI files.

But this does not help the OP. The easiest way **to preserve this type of workflow while still having the ability to toggle visibility without manual relinking is to abandon artboards and rely on layers** to organize the various options.

Answer (score 0):

These may not be what your looking for, but what if you save the file as an EPS WITH the option checked "use artboards". 
[image]
[image]
This should save out every artboard as a separate file AND save you a 'Master' EPS.

Note: when the files are save out they are Label as such: `fileName_Artboard Name`

[image]

Then in InDesign you just import each icon as separate file. Note: You still will able to edit with the 'Master' EPS.

I know this doesn't solve your problem with .AI files but it is a workaround (This works with SVG also).

Answer (score -1):

Moved from a comment... to an answer....

I don't think you can to be honest. Primarily since the file is linked correctly and you merely want to change the *import options*.

There's no feature I'm aware of to alter import options on more than one image at a time. Using separate files rather than artboards would be easier, but I have no idea if that's feasible in your situation.

Comment: Why the down vote?